# Packaging OpenSSL w/ Application

Tags: openssl, certificate

I'm looking to package a copy of OpenSSL with an application, and that application would then be installed on other computers.

I can't seem to find any information on this on the web, which either means what I'm attempting is silly, or I'm not using the right search terms. Regardless ...

The idea is: the application generates its own self-signed certificate every time it is launched. It then uses that certificate until the application is closed, and then generates a new one once it is launched again. Rinse and repeat. As I understand it, certificates can be generated through the cmd prompt (I'm using Windows 10). My current solution is that the application writes its own batch script (which creates the certificate) and then executes it.

```
@echo on
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -subj '/C=CA/ST=Ontario/L=Toronto/O=Company/OU=Org/CN=localhost'
```

The batch script needs to use the "openssl" command to create the certificate, which is where the complications arise. The odds of someone having OpenSSL installed on their comp are not great, so I need to find a way to install OpenSSL on another computer with the application in order to use the batch script ... hence the desire to package the two together.

Now that I've written this down, it does sound needlessly complicated, so I'm thinking there's a better way to solve this problem, but I'm still fresh as to what OpenSSL's capabilities are.

If there is a way to package OpenSSL with an application, any information on that would be greatly appreciated. Or, if there is a way to create self-signed certificates without using cmd, that would be great too.

Alternatively, if there is a better way to do this, I am of course open to suggestions.

Thanks for any and all help.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out how to package OpenSSL with an application. Is it the right way? I'm sure it could be better ... but does it work? It did for me.

I added the the Windows installer that was downloaded from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html (I'm using 1.0.2p) to the application package.

During installation the application will check to see if OpenSSL 1.0.2p is already installed on this computer by checking the .dll's (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) in the System32 folder (or if they are there at all).

If they are not present, the application will write a batch file (LaunchInstaller.bat) in its own directory.

```
@echo on
InstallOpenSSL.exe /SP- /SILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOCANCEL /NORESTART /DIR=<Whatever The User's Install Directory Is> /NOICONS
```

It will then launch the .bat file - I used CreateProcess - to install OpenSSL on the machine in its own directory.

Then the application will have access to all it needs in order to generate a new Cert every time the application is started.

Cheers and I hope this helps someone.